# How can I avoid having duplicate issues in SonarQube IDE plugin?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to use SonarQube Eclipse plugin (version 3.4) along with SonarQube version 3.7.4, Eclipse Kepler and a mulit-modules maven project and I'm facing the following issue.

After having run a local analysis (in preview mode as incremental mode is not possible with 3.7.4) , all issues appear twice. I checked their properties and see that I have for each issue A the following :

- A1. issue that is created before the local analysis (probably taken from server)
- A2. issue that is added after the local analysis

Both are marked in the view as being "old issues" (new issue = false.)

If I add new issues, they are correctly added to the list. However if I fix an old issue, A2 is removed but A1 still remains in the view (which is rather annoying).

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a way in order to have only issues displayed once ?

Note : the Eclipse project is correctly associated to the SonarQube component (I'm working with multi-modules projects)

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know bug that is referenced here: [SONARIDE-426](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARIDE-426)

Feel free to watch it and vote for it.